# Customising A Dropdown Search Bar In The Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, blogger

I would like help in customising the css for a dropdown search bar that appears on my hovering navigation bar. An example of such an element can be viewed on the following blog - http://www.theprivatelifeofagirl.com/ - in the top right hand side corner of the navbar.

The current coding I have is roughly what I envisioned for the element to look like however I'm unable to move the element to the left, and visible on the screen. At the moment it is far too towards the right side and hence invisible to readers. I have included the relevant html and css coding for the search bar below :

```
<style>
.show-search {
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
right: -1px;
display: none;
z-index: 10000;
}

.show-search #searchform input#s {
width: 190px;
background: #FFF;
webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(206, 206, 206, .2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(206, 206, 206, .2);
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(206, 206, 206, .2);
}

.show-search #searchform input#s:focus {
border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
.searchborder {
border-left: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
right: 10px;
bottom: 0px;
height: 50px;
  } 
</style>

<div class='searchborder'>
<div id='top-search'>
  <a href='#'><i class='search'></i></a>
</div>
<div class='show-search'>
  <form action='/search' id='searchform' method='get' role='search'>
    <div>
      <input id='s' name='q' placeholder='Search' type='text' />
    </div>
  </form></div>
</div>
```

In addition to moving the element slightly to the left, I would also like to know how to customise the search bar itself. For example how to change the color of the font, the border color etc.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.